# Codeigniter 'GET' error 404 during navigation

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

SOLVED: 
thanks to Accountant.

I'm making a simple web app with codeigniter and want to navigate between different pages. 
I have used this line of code to link to another page:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('canvas');?>" title="Canvas link">Canvas</a>
```

When I click this link I am taken to the correct except all of the image buttons etc show up as 404 not found..
When I use the same 'canvas' page as the route default controller it all loads perfectly.
I don't know what could be the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: the images `src`s might be relative urls "related to the current document location"

Comment: @Accountantم this is indeed the problem thank you for that!

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: @Accountantم great thank you. I've added new code above. How can I do this in my javascript file? I need the images to be loaded there so that I can scale the image to the canvas size. I'm still getting 404 with the above code.

Comment: what if you try with base_url()?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not removed the index.php in config.php located in config folder.
then add it to your URL

```
<?php echo site_url().'index.php/canvas';?>
```